# dispatch_after recursion vs NSTimer scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval

Tags: ios, recursion, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer, dispatch

I read a code, it checks data and update UI every second. It sounds like what we usually do using `NSTimer scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval`. But this code is implemented with recursively calling `dispatch_after` like this:

```
- (void) retriggerMethod {
    ... do stuff here, assuming you want to do it on first invocation ...
    dispatch_after( ..., ^{
        [self retriggerMethod];
    });
}
```

What's the difference between ***dispatch_after recursion*** and ***NSTimer scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval*** ? Is there potential risk when using the former? Cos I thought when you use it, the call stack would grow as long as not end this recursion.

Answer (score 9):

NSTimer:

```
1. Need a NSRunloop.
2. Can repeat.
3. Can be invalid anytime if u want to cancel.
4. Can only run with delegate.
5. High level API.
```

dispatch_after:

```
1. Can be run everywhere that u want with dispatch_queue.
2. Can't repeat by itself.
3. Can't be cancel.
4. It run as block.
5. GCD.
```

Answer (score 4):

You actually don't have any recursion in your code. Using `dispatch_after` in your case behaves similar to using a NSTimer.

With `dispatch_after`, the next call to your `retriggerMethod` originates from GCD which executes the enqueued block. So you don't have a call within a call - no recursion here.

So in terms of recursion, there's no risk. Though in this case it seems more reasonable to use a `NSTimer` which would be easier to cancel if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is really late, but a couple additional considerations now:

1. cancelling difference is not a huge deal

`dispatch_after` does accepts workItems which can be cancelled about as easily as a timer can.

2. time slipping

For a high number of repetitions `dispach_after` recursion could slip in accuracy by a lot. Each slip is compounded into the next recursion, since the next recursion is set only after executing the previous recursion. Say for example dispatch_after may slip up to 10ms. That means after 100 recursions, it may have slipped up to 1 second.

In comparison, while each tick of the `NSTimer` may also be up to 10ms off (for example), later ticks won't ever slip more than 10ms that since each tick time is relative to the original scheduled time.